# Firebase | How can I change the App Distribution's App Icon

Tags: ios, firebase, app-distribution, firebase-app-distribution

I migrated Fabric project to Firebase. But I can't find any options for an app icon in the App Distribution.

How can I change my app icon?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sending a new build with a new app icon can be a solution. 
Yesterday I sent wrong which belongs to another app and the app icon changed to the new build's app icon.